# a way not to make new line for using scanf?

Tags: c

I found whenever I put input using scanf, and then pressing enter key to put the value into variable, it automatically makes new line.

For example,

```
write any float : 12.34
here is your type : 12.34
```

I don't want above but I want it to be like below,

```
write any float : 12.34 here is your type : 12.34
```

How can I do this? if there is no way to do this using scanf, please let me know alternative.

Thank you very much.

Comment: did you try fcanf() ?? because in compiler it is delimited by newline which can't be stopped I think

Comment: You are describing the behavior of the console or terminal you use, it has nothing to do with scanf().  The user interface of a C program has not made much progress in the past 40 years, but your OS certainly has better options available today.

Comment: @NeoR you mean fscanf? i can't find fcanf function..

Comment: @HansPassant that sounds like the result I want is just impossible lol thank you

Comment: You can change the mode of the terminal to 'raw' mode rather than the default 'cooked' mode, Then use the functions to detect a key press and input that key, then the user does not need to press the 'enter' key.  However, such 1) should always change back to 'cooked' mode before exiting the program and 2) the program needs to do everything as nothing (backspace, newline, etc) are handled automatically

Comment: you can use the terminal/ansi  escape sequences to move the cursor up one line and over to the right, past the user input,  Then output the 'here is your type: ...'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot in a portable way.

The rationale behind is that keyboard input is normally echoed and line oriented to allow backspace processing at low level and only present a validated input to the program. The counterpart is that input is only available when the new line key (Enter) is hit, and that (because of the echo) automatically causes the cursor to go at the beginning of a new line.

What are the possibilities:

- use a full GUI program. You have input fields on a window and the validation is normally done by clicking a button
- use a screen positionning library. `curses` is a well known library in the Unix-Linux world, but ports exists for the Windows world. That allows to position the cursor at an absolute position on the screen and as such to move it immediately after the previous input.
- use raw input - what curses does under the hood. All incoming characters directly hit the program and no automatic echo occurs. You must be prepared to echo each received character (the way you want, if you want to automatically upper- or lowercase input, you can), including backspace. That's really low level processing, and unfortunately it works differently in Windows (search for conio functions) and Unix-Linux (search for raw vs cooked input)
- accept it. Going to the next line after each and every input is anyway common and should not surprise user.